# MAKE Error installing Sphinx -Arch Linux

Tags: sphinx

I am seeming to have the same problem as [this guy:](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=7841)

I am using XAMPP on Arch Linux with every package updated to the latest rev.

```
$ make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory «.../src»
/bin/sh svnxrev.sh ..
make all-am
make[2]: Entering directory «/home/sphinx/src»
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../config -DSYSCONFDIR="\"/home/sphinx/sphinx_bin/etc\""
-DDATADIR="\"/home/sphinx/sphinx_bin/var/data\"" -I/usr/local/include -I/mysql/include
-I/mysq/include -L/mysql/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/mysql/lib -fno-exceptions -g -Wall -g
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3 -DNDEBUG -MT sphinx.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/sphinx.Tpo -c -o
sphinx.o sphinx.cpp
sphinx.cpp: In constructor �?WordformContainer_t::WordformContainer_t()’:
sphinx.cpp:15614:27: warning: �?WordformContainer_t::m_pMultiWordforms’ will be
initialized after
sphinx.cpp:15611:15: warning: �?uint64_t WordformContainer_t::m_uTokenizerFNV’
sphinx.cpp:15904:1: warning: when initialized here
sphinx.cpp: In function �?int xmlUnknownEncoding(void*, const XML_Char*,
XML_Encoding*)’:
sphinx.cpp:21575:10: error: �?XML_STATUS_ERROR’ was not declared in this scope
sphinx.cpp:21599:9: error: �?XML_STATUS_OK’ was not declared in this scope
sphinx.cpp: In member function �?bool CSphSource_XMLPipe2::ParseNextChunk(int,
CSphString&)’:
sphinx.cpp:22112:76: error: �?XML_STATUS_OK’ was not declared in this scope
sphinx.cpp: In function �?int xmlUnknownEncoding(void*, const XML_Char*,
XML_Encoding*)’:
sphinx.cpp:21600:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
make[2]: *** [sphinx.o] Error 1
make[2]: leaving directory «/home/sphinx/src»
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: leaving directory «/home/sphinx/src»
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Comments in [AUR package](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=17178) might help. Two source files will need to be modified before compiling.

```
[arch ~]# tar zxf sphinx-2.0.4-release.tar.gz
[arch ~]# cd sphinx-2.0.4-release
[arch sphinx-2.0.4-release]# sed -i 's/T val = ExprEval/T val = this->ExprEval/g' "src/sphinxexpr.cpp"
[arch sphinx-2.0.4-release]# sed -i '15083,15083 s/x00/x21/' "src/searchd.cpp"
[arch sphinx-2.0.4-release]# make
[arch sphinx-2.0.4-release]# make install
```

Answer (score 1):

emcconville's solution works great with http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-sphinx-plugin/ plugin installation which uses obsolete sphinx-0.9.9.
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
package was also prerequisite on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

That problem was caused by having 2 instances of expat installed.

I got around that error only to run into more down the road. The best solution is to ditch xampp and install mysql/php/perl/etc manually.